# ERROR 1143 (42000): SELECT command denied

Tags: mysql

I use a user who has the update privileges to execute a sql:

```
update stu set age = 27 where name='zjw';
```

I got this error:

> ERROR 1143 (42000): SELECT command denied to user
>   'update_user'@'localhost' for column 'name' in table 'stu'

The table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `stu` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

update_user's privileges is:

```
grant update on *.* to 'update_user'@'%';
```

MySQL version is 5.1.73.

thanks.

Comment: The error is about the **SELECT** privilege, and yet you give the **UPDATE** ... why don't you try giving the privilege which is actually causing the error?

Comment: The error `ERROR 1143 (42000): SELECT command denied to user` seems pretty specific. Does the user only have UPDATE rights? Or does it also have SELECT rights. When looking at the error, granting SELECT rights might seem to solve your issue.

Comment: After i give select privileges to the user,the error is disappeared.
But i also confuse why the user has update privilege,but it can't update the data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you execute

```
UPDATE `stu` SET age = 27 WHERE name = 'zjw';
```

the SQL engine has to first select the rows it needs to update.

Therefore, if you do not have the `SELECT` privilege, you cannot perform such update, even if you have the `UPDATE` privilege.

Check out the Manual for the [Grant Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's what i confused.

Answer (score 2):

@Robin as per your last comment, try to understand your update statement-

```
UPDATE `stu` SET age = 27 WHERE name = 'zjw';
```

Your above update statement first try to fetch the records where name='zjw', so if your name column is indexed then select use index and select directly only records those have value 'zjw' else it will scan whole table and select 'zjw' wherever in table.

Means first mysql use select statement internally before update, so you also need select privileges with any other privileges like update/delete etc.

so your grant command should be-

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE on db.* to 'myuser'@'localhost' identified by 'mypass';
```

You should give permission only specific IP or localhost as per requirement instead of globally by '%' which is risky.

Comment: Your answer is so good, thank you.
I tried this sql:update stu set age=27 
without where-clause, it is right.
Tks again.

Answer (score 0):

because when `where` clause is used in `update`, the datebase will `select` the rows that meet the `where` condition, so `select` privilege is needed while granting `update` privilege.

> The SELECT privilege is also needed for other statements that read column values. For example, SELECT is needed for columns referenced on the right hand side of col_name=expr assignment in UPDATE statements or for columns named in the WHERE clause of DELETE or UPDATE statements.

[mysql manual here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_select)